# Displaying images from a database using pdo but it only shows broken images

Tags: php, database, pdo

[image]

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='text' required="required" name='activityName' placeholder="Name of the activity..."><br><br>
    <input type='date' required="required" name='date'><br><br>
    <input type='file' required="required" name='file'><br><br>
    <button type='submit' name='submit'>Upload</button>
</form>
<?php

$ps = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM activities");

echo "<br>";
echo "<table>";
while($row = $ps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo $row['name']; echo "</td>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

The following code is what I'm using to upload to the database..

```
<?php

include 'dbh.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $activityName = $_POST['activityName'];
    $activityDate = $_POST['date'];



    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allow = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allow)){

        if($fileError === 0){
            if ($fileSize < 1000000){
                $fileNewName = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = '/home/bh03te/public_html/webproject/uploads/' . $fileNewName;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileDestination);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO activities (name, date, image) VALUES ('$activityName', $activityDate, '$fileNewName')";
                $result = $pdo->query($sql); 

                header("Location: activities.php?uploadsuccess");
            } else{
                echo "This file is too large";
            }
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading this file";
        }

    } else{
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }

}
```

This is all the code I do have for it and don't see why it isn't working. Do I need to have the data type in the database as something specific? It is currently just VARCHAR. I don't know if it would make a difference or not. All the names from the database and everything is correct as images do upload but they just don't echo out correctly. It only outputs a broken image.

Comment: Can you provide sample values as seen in the database?

Comment: I would like to know if the HTML printed out is correct, I mean, if the string for the file is correctly spelled and points to the right path. Plus, why not just concatenate the strings? (Not relevant to the issue, but that makes a cleaner code in my opinion).

Comment: Show us how you stored the image to the database

Comment: @Zeke I've added the form above if that's what you were asking for. And I'm fairly new to php so I'm just going with it for now

Comment: Also, within your loop you have `</table>` (should be under your loop) and no `</tr>` (should be in the place of `</table>`) which will break your table.

Comment: How is the image stored in the DB? `/images/1.jpg`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly added

Comment: So you are getting a 404 with requests like `/home/bh03te/public_html/webproject/uploads/1.jpg`? Where does you web path start at? I'd guess `/home/bh03te/public_html/` is not web accessible.

Comment: @chris85 do you want the link to the site?

Comment: @Enstage okay thanks

Comment: You can check that, open the developer console and see. I don't have access you your server configuration so I cant (without removing dirs until I find the real path) tell you what dir it should be.

Comment: @chris85 theres no problem with the directory, everything uploads fine and there's other things that are outputting fine, its just the images which appear broken

Comment: `http://www.example.com/home/bh03te/public_html/webproject/uploads/imagename.jpg` loads for you? Open the developer console and look at the network tab for what your images are requesting as.

Comment: @chris85 its a uni server i don't think i can just put it out there

Comment: Post the URL, this will probably be faster.

Comment: @chris85 you literally don't need to see it, anything that is relevant is already in the question above, ill post a picture of what it looks like if that helps

Comment: True I don't. Please do what I asked 14 minutes ago in that case then. `Open the developer console and look at the network tab for what your images are requesting as`. Compare that to the server's actual configuration and correct.

Comment: @chris85 I don't know how to do this, it's on Netbeans and I can't find it

Comment: In your browser, are you using chrome? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: @chris85 ohhh right, I didn't even know about that, it says the source is unknown....   <img src=(unknown) height="100" width="100">

Comment: Interesting... do you see any console error regarding to a load failure? As in a 404 file not found?

Comment: @Zeke no nothing like that

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen that. View the page source, copy the `src` value, replace the domain/IP with `example.com` and provide that here.

Comment: the src value of the images? there literally isnt one, this is what it shows... <img  src="" height="100" width="100">, is there a way I could PM you, might make this go a lot quicker

Comment: I don't think chat is available to you yet. It usually prompts a link at some point in the conversation. Does `$row` have the `image` index? `var_dump($row);`

Comment: all i get is bool(false) and no, i don't use this much

Comment: You need to be much more careful in terms of sanitizing that input.For example,  assume it is going to be either executable php (by having php as a segment in the name anywhere), javascript or SQL.    Everyone else has already explained what the problem is with your path. And you may want to scan the file also unless your upload.php is doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing your file is already uploading correctly, and I see you are not saving the entire path of the image on the database, therefore you also need to write it down in the `src` attribute of the image before the name of the file (with its extension).

Either do it when printing:

```
// I am deleting everything up to public_html because I suppose that's the DOCUMENT_ROOT, so that's not web accessible
<img src="/webproject/uploads/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height="100" width="100">
```

Or when inserting into the database:

```
// I am deleting everything up to public_html because I suppose that's the DOCUMENT_ROOT, so that's not web accessible
$path = '/webproject/uploads/'.$fileNewName;
$sql = "INSERT INTO activities (name, date, image) VALUES ('$activityName', $activityDate, '$path')";
```

Comment: i added the second part its made no difference unfortunately

Comment: Did you make sure that was the web accessible path anyway? Because with the code in the question will tell the browser that the image is in the document root, just like @chris85 said. You must find the correct public path to the image and print whatever that is.

Comment: You don't need/want the `/webproject/uploads/` in the `src`. You are having the OP write the path as relative (in the insert) so it should load without those dirs. As is OP would get `<img src="/webproject/uploads//webproject/uploads/filename"`. But you are on the right path.

Comment: One more thing to do is to check if move_uploaded_file was successful before writing values to DB.

Comment: I supposed the picture was somewhere else, which is what people would usually do I believe, that's all. What's important is to stress that the `src` attribute needs to point to an accessible, existing, either relative or absolute path.

Comment: It is better to prepend the path in your html in case you ever have to move your site.  Even better make a constant.

Comment: @Ellin agreed, still there's definitely a problem on the fetch or insert because as discussed in the comments, the code in the question is returning nothing at all, plus the console reports `(unknown)`. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the raw image data along with its mime type, then create a php file that sets the header to the right contentType before the raw image data is echoed.

E.g.

```
<img src="getImg.php" height="100" width="100" />
```

PHP:

```
<?php header("contentType:".$mime); echo $raw_img; ?>
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do that

Comment: What is the advantage to doing this over the file storage method the OP is currently using?

Comment: I didn't even read the code to see that they were stored on the filesystem. I just concluded immediately I saw "The following code is what I'm using to upload to the database." Filesystem approach is better, faster and also cached. @chris85

Comment: You're not really using the file system here though. Images won't be cached with this approach; or you need more information because `getImg.php` is just going to server 1 image.